# media query not dispalying

Tags: css, media-queries

I am struggling with a website regarding media queries. I have this code snippet as part of my menu

`.flexnav.flexnav-show {
   margin-top: 52px; }` line 513 in my css
and with a media query set at @media all and (min-width: 800px) I have this code snippet for my tablet.

`.flexnav.flexnav-show {
      margin-top: 0px; }`  on line 638 in my css

However, when viewing the page on a tablet the margin-top is still set at 52px.
I have a similar issue with a another media query. I have this following code snippet

`@media only screen and (min-width: 481px)
header hgroup {
top: 12%;
}`
For my desktop I have the following:

`@media only screen and (min-width: 769px)
header hgroup {
    top:15%;
}` at line 462

When on the desktop the top is still 12%

This is the [link](http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/Index.html) to the website.
Thanks
-Sohail

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "max-width"
EXAMPLE:

```
/* DEFAULT */
.some-div{top:30%;}
/* RESPONSIVE */
@media screen and (max-width: 769px){
.some-div{ top:15%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 481px){
.some-div{ top: 12%;}
}
```

Sometimes you can use "!important" to rewrite the previous state in CSS but is not necessarily.

Comment: Sorry, what you tried. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: When I tried to replace my media query with your example, the header vanished for both the tablet and desktop and the menu for the desktop turned into a vertical menu as the for the for the phone and tablet and not the horizontal menu as it should be for the desktop

Comment: Do you try to replace ".some-div" with your class? You only need to change from '@media only screen and (min-width: 481px)' to '@media only screen and (max-width: 481px)'. Look source of my website like [example](http://onlinepresskit247.com/css/responsive.css)

Comment: I solved the problem for the header with following:
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
header hgroup {
 top:15% !important;
}
}

Comment: But for the menu I think that I am actually missing a media query specifically for the tablet, that puts .flexnav-show {
   margin-top:0px;
  } the default for that is now margin-top: 52px; upto @media all and (min-width: 800px)

Comment: When you do a responsive, sometimes you need to play and you need to know all display sizes. I will give you my guide: **[Responsive design device resolution reference](http://spirelightmedia.com/resources/responsive-design-device-resolution-reference)** You need to create media query for all sizes and somethimes use javascript to support your CSS.